# Message Compiler Failed trying to parse file. The parameter is incorrect

Tags: winapi

When invoking mc.exe with a given manifest file I'm getting the following error:

error : Failed trying to parse file. (null)(0): Error 0x80070057. At Line=0, Column=0, The parameter is incorrect.

I suspect this to be an issue with an env variable or file being used by MC as I'm using a valid manifest and it was working previously. The command I'm using is:

mc.exe "MyManifest.man" -z "MyManifest"

Answer (score 0):

Clean up %temp% directory solved problem for me.
MC.EXE created tempory files and didn't clean that.